# Getting a random row from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to get a random row from my table by id.

My table:

```
ID|Word     |Dificult|Category_id|
1 |'Dumb'   |'Easy'  | 3         |
2 |'Leopard'|'Medium'| 6         |
```

If my user selects a category and a difficult, I have pick a random word with user parameters, like:

```
idRaffle := raffle.id;
   -- raffle.id = An id that postgres will bring me by some raffle function. 
d := 'Easy';
c := 3;
select * from words where id=idRaffle and Dificult=d and Category_id=c

raffle.id
```

I don't know how to get that random row id (`raffle.id`).

Note that it must follow the user's selection conditions.

Comment: So you want a random row (from the many) that fit the `Difficult = 'Easy' AND Category_id = 3` ?

Comment: Excacly, how can I do this?

Comment: [Closely related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8674718/939860). `ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1` is actually rather slow because it needs to scan and sort the whole table. Fine for small tables, impractical for big tables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To pick a random row, see:

[quick random row selection in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297396/quick-random-row-selection-in-postgres)

```
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE Difficult = 'Easy' AND Category_id = 3
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1;
```

Since 9.5 there's also the [`TABLESAMPLE` option](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/); see [documentation for `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) for details on `TABLESAMPLE`.

Comment: This way is very slow

Comment: Yes, it is. This isn't a use case SQL was really specified for. However newer PostgreSQL versions have tablesample support now.